# How do I remove all unofficial packages and revert to official ones?

Tags: apt, package-management, testing, quality

An Ubuntu developer asked me to perform tests on some unofficial packages. Now my system is broken and I can't get support because I have unofficial packages installed. The package did not come from a PPA. How do I remove the developer's packages and revert to using only the official repos?

I'm looking for a canonical answer that works for any package or packages because this happens a lot.

Comment: One answer: Check /var/log/apt to see exactly which packages were installed. Those  are the packages you must revert. Use `apt-cache policy` on each of those packages to learn the Ubuntu version number. Use `apt install version=` to install the correct version of each package. In the future, it may be easier to test using a disposable session (LiveUSB or VM)

Comment: maybe `apt-show-versions | fgrep newer`  and `apt-show-versions | fgrep avail` can help to identify this packages.

Comment: Since there are many ways a package could be installed, the only general answer is "Using the same system you used to install the package, remove it".

Comment: Or, investigate the `ppa-purge` package.